# What's the reason for this time difference?

Tags: opencv, optimization, android-ndk, mat, gcc4.9

there is some problem with my code

In follow code:
`GainDetailMatI` is `Mat` type with 9792*2448 matrix
`ContrastGainBound4096x`,`ContrastGainLayerI`  is `int`
Platform: Android 4.4, NDK gcc 4.9

A:

```
Mat plus = ContrastGainLayerI * min(ContrastGainBound4096x, max(0, GainDetailMatI - 4096.0));
```

B:

```
Mat t=max(0, GainDetailMatI - 4096.0);
Mat plus = ContrastGainLayerI * min(ContrastGainBound4096x, t);
```

A use 13 millisec more than B.
I close gcc optimize by set `APP_OPTIM := debug` at Application.mk

Is there anyone know the reason?
I think maybe `max(0, GainDetailMatI - 4096.0)` return with type `MatExpr`
And `t=max(0, GainDetailMatI - 4096.0);` convert `MatExpr` to `Mat`
Maybe this is the reason?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

In example B you first store the object in t, retrieving it to use in the second part of your code. In example A you skip the storing and retrieving making the code more efficient. While this shows that dumping all your code on one line often makes it more efficient, keep in mind that readablility has ALOT of value. More info on Java performance can be found on the wiki. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_performance#Compressed_Oops

Comment: But in my situation, Case B is faster than A.    
It doesn't make sense.

Comment: Ah, apologies i misread that part of your question. Then that means you are probably right that conversion to Mat takes sometime when you place it inline like that.

Comment: Yeah,both case with A and B have convert to mat ,this is rewlly unreasonable,maybe I need to check GCC compiled object code?

Comment: Perhaps, but im afraid i wont be able to help you more than this while a have some knowledge about optimization i really dont know why B is faster then A. My apologies.